# The part of my code where a search for a name in a string isnt working.(it always says it doesnt exist) Any ideas

Tags: c++

In int menu() i have 2 options how to add ships

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Ship input() {  //to input info for 1 ship
    Ship S = { 0 };
    cout << "\n Enter ship number:"; cin >> S.number;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\n Enter the name of the ship:"; cin.getline(S.name, 50);
    cout << "\n Enter the load capacity of the ship:"; cin >> S.capacity;


    return (S);
}

int enter(Ship Lib[], int n) { //to input infor for multiple ships
    int i, m;
    do {
        cout << "\n Enter information for how many ships(max 5 in one go):";
        cin >> m;
    } while (m < 0 || m>5);
    if (n + m < 20) { // max number of ships i can have is 20
        for (i = n; i < n + m; i++) {
            cout << "\n Ship " << i + 1;
            Lib[i] = input();
        }
        return (n + m);

    }
    else cout << "\n You can't add any more ships!";

}

void Ship_by_Name(Ship Lib[], int n) { //search for a ship by its name
    char Sname[50];
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\n Ship name: ";
    cin.getline(Sname, 50);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        if (!strcmp(Sname, Lib[i].name)) {
            cout << "\n Ship found!";
            cout << "\n Number: " << Lib[i].number << "\t Name: " << Lib[i].name << "\t Load capacity: "
                << Lib[i].capacity;
            break; //how i break the loop when i find what i need

        }
        else cout << "\n This ship isn't recorded!"; //this line prints 3 times?
}
```

But i think void Ship_by_Name has no access to Ship input now that im looking at it.
So i think i need to make it available to Ship_by_name somehow

Comment: You always only test with the first ship in the list. Does it work if you enter the Ship name that is the first one in the list?

Comment: Add `cout << i << endl;` inside the loop.

Comment: For such problems, you should use a debugger and step through your code line by line. That way you will see if the file is correctly read, and which comparisons are made or not made.

Comment: This is C++ – why are your using a C-style char array for `Sname` instead of a `std::string`? Why do you pass a C-style array of `Ship` and a length instead of a `std::vector<Ship>` (even better: a `const std::vector<Ship>&`? doing both would almost certainly get rid of out-of-bound errors caused by inconsistent lengths. This is one of the main reasons people use C++ instead of C! (hint: whatever you learn C++ with seems to be written by someone who doesn't know much C++, but more C; if you have the choice, find a different resource: this is training you to write bad code.)

Comment: It doesnt work no matter the order of the names. I'll try with debugging.

Comment: Im still new to coding so the code I've typed reflects my knowledge is very basic(I still haven't gotten to vectors and ect.).

Comment: @floodx, why are using `break` in else? So, if the user input is not at the first of your array, then it will immediately exit the loop and will not check the other elements

Comment: @kuro I don't know how else to prevent th loop  from typing out "This ship isnt recorded" more than it needs to

Comment: Read the loop out loud to yourself, iteration by iteration: "If the name of the first element matches, print 'Ship found!...' and continue with the next element. Otherwise, print 'This ship is not recorded' and break out of the loop." Doesn't sound quite right, does it?

Comment: @floodx, the print statement is not the problem. The problem is the `break`. Due to this the loop will exit. Try your code without the `break`. At least it will find the element is array if it is actually in the array

Comment: Think a bit more about the logic. If you have found a match, do you really need to keep looking for one? Do you really know that you haven't found any match before you have examined *all* the elements (i.e. inside the loop)?

Comment: @molbdnilo So when i find the matching name i should break out of the loop? But this doesn't solve the issue of not finding the name when its there.

Comment: @floodx fix one thing after the other. Follow mobdnilo's instructions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller OK, im getting too ahead of myself, i'll try to solve the problem with the loop!

Comment: I can't come up with a way to resolve the problem.

Comment: @floodx, did you follow molbdnilo's instructions? What problem are you facing now?

Comment: @kuro I cant think of how to get out of the loop once i find what im looking for

Comment: @floodx, you can do that using `break`. As you have a function, you can do the same by returning from the function as well

Comment: @ kuro Yeah i used break after printing the ship info on the screen, but I don't know if it helped because when i went to run the code the cout in else printed 3 times. I can't understand where the problem lays unfortunately.

Comment: @floodx, can you update the question with your updated code? Also are you sure that the user input is present in the array?

Comment: @kuro I updateded it, please check it out!

Comment: I was able to make searching it by name work however the problem of not exiting the loop and printing "Ship not found" until it finds it arose alongside  inputting the wrong amount of ships

Comment: @floodx, your loop checks each entry of the array with user input name. So, for each entry which has different name, the `else` block will print "Ship not found". So, in this case better to use `return` instead of `break` in the loop when name matches. You can remove the `else` part entirely and add the "Ship not found" print statement after the loop. Then it will only print when ship is not found and it will print only once